# iOS Push notification - not guaranteed

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I have made a PushChatStarter app for Push Notification from this tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2

But I find that only some of the messages are being successfully sent. It is mentioned in the tutorial that the push notifications are not guaranteed. I would like to know the reason why this is happening.

I could not understand the solution mentioned in that tutorial. Could anyone explain how to obtain the solution. I would like to know how to make the application reliable.

Comment: Note: they don't say unreliable, they say not guaranteed. Big world of difference. In practise Push Message is reasonably reliable (after all it's used by tens of thousands of apps to push millions of notifications), but there's no guarantee it'll arrive. Your problem is likely to be elsewhere than the Push Notification service.

Comment: I am facing this issue... Notifications don't arrive sometimes. I check the logs ... FCM token is there and the server sends the notification but the user some time did not get the notifications... I am unable to convince clint that this issue is not form my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

```
Quality of Service

Apple Push Notification Service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that
performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the      device 
is offline, the QoS stores the notification. It retains only one notification per application 
on a device: the last notification received from a provider for that application. 
When the offline device later reconnects, the QoS forwards the stored notification to the device.
The QoS retains a notification for a limited period before deleting it.
```

Comment: provided link not working any more ....

Comment: And I believe, APNs retains one notification but FCM retains 1oo notifications means this should not happen on FCM ...